# Replace placeholder by selected text when macro is triggered in TexStudio

Tags: macros, texstudio

I want to write a macro that puts `$` around the selected text when I press the `$` key like TexStudio does it for braces and brackets.

So far, I have tried

```
%SCRIPT
txt = cursor.selectedText()
editor.write("$"+txt+"$")
cursor.clearSelection()
```

and

```
$%<math%:multiline%>$
```

both with the trigger `\$`. These two macros surround the selected text by `$` when I use their keyboard shortcut, but they erase it when I use the trigger. Does anyone knows how to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible the way you are trying it because the selection is cleared before the macro gets executed.

As a workaround you can use the following script

```
%SCRIPT
text = '$'
if (cursor.hasSelection()) {
    text = '$' + cursor.selectedText() + '$'
}
cursor.insertText(text)
```

and assign `$` as a shortcut the options. (Note: when trying to set the shortcut, you may get `Shift+$`. In this case, you have to delete the additional text in the combo box so that only `$` remains (you can move the cursor and use `Del` / `Backspace`).

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought about simply assigning `$` as the keyboard shortcut, works perfectly.